# Installation using pip on a conda env is taking a very long time

Tags: python, pip, conda

I am trying to install the below requirements contained in a `requirements.txt` file in a conda environment:

```
amazon-braket-pennylane-plugin==1.1.0.post1
cvxopt==1.2.6
cvxpy==1.1.11
dill==0.3.3
ipywidgets==7.6.3
jupyter==1.0.0
jupytext==1.10.2
matplotlib==3.3.4
Mosek==9.2.40
notebook==6.2.0
numpy==1.19.5
pandas==1.2.2
pytest==6.2.2
scikit-learn==0.24.1
scipy==1.6.0
seaborn==0.11.1
sklearn==0.0
sympy==1.7.1
tqdm==4.57.0
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
pennylane==0.16.0
pennylane-cirq==0.14.0
keras==2.4.3
tensorflow==2.4.1
rsmf==0.2
```

The command I am using is:

```
pip install -r src/requirements.txt --upgrade
```

[github](https://github.com/thubregtsen/qhack)

But the installation does not complete and is continuing for many hours as shown below. I am not sure why it is taking so long and what I should do to install the software correctly.

```
Downloading protobuf-3.20.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.0/1.0 MB 94.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0
  Downloading google_api_core-1.34.0-py3-none-any.whl (120 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 120.2/120.2 kB 48.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pyquil>=3.2.0
  Downloading pyquil-3.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 221.6/221.6 kB 47.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting psutil
  Downloading psutil-5.9.4-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (280 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 280.2/280.2 kB 74.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting debugpy>=1.6.5
  Downloading debugpy-1.6.6-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.1/3.1 MB 83.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting comm>=0.1.1
  Downloading comm-0.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
Collecting matplotlib-inline>=0.1
  Downloading matplotlib_inline-0.1.6-py3-none-any.whl (9.4 kB)
Collecting pygments>=2.4.0
  Downloading Pygments-2.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.1/1.1 MB 93.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting stack-data
  Downloading stack_data-0.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting prompt-toolkit!=3.0.37,<3.1.0,>=3.0.30
  Downloading prompt_toolkit-3.0.38-py3-none-any.whl (385 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 385.8/385.8 kB 84.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting backcall
  Downloading backcall-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting pexpect>4.3
  Using cached pexpect-4.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Collecting decorator
  Downloading decorator-5.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.1 kB)
Collecting pickleshare
  Using cached pickleshare-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9 kB)
Collecting jedi>=0.16
  Downloading jedi-0.18.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.6/1.6 MB 111.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting importlib-metadata>=4.8.3
  Downloading importlib_metadata-6.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting platformdirs>=2.5
  Downloading platformdirs-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting mdit-py-plugins~=0.2.1
  Downloading mdit_py_plugins-0.2.8-py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 41.0/41.0 kB 16.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting attrs>=19.2.0
  Downloading attrs-20.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 49.3/49.3 kB 18.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting jsonschema>=2.6
  Downloading jsonschema-4.17.3-py3-none-any.whl (90 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 90.4/90.4 kB 31.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting fastjsonschema
  Downloading fastjsonschema-2.16.3-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting qdldl
  Downloading qdldl-0.1.5.post3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.0/1.0 MB 95.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tensorboard-data-server<0.8.0,>=0.7.0
  Downloading tensorboard_data_server-0.7.0-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (6.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 6.6/6.6 MB 97.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tensorboard~=2.4
  Downloading tensorboard-2.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (6.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 6.0/6.0 MB 98.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting google-auth<3,>=1.6.3
  Downloading google_auth-2.17.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 178.1/178.1 kB 66.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8
  Downloading Markdown-3.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 93.9/93.9 kB 39.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tensorboard-data-server<0.7.0,>=0.6.0
  Using cached tensorboard_data_server-0.6.1-py3-none-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (4.9 MB)
Collecting werkzeug>=1.0.1
  Downloading Werkzeug-2.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (233 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 233.6/233.6 kB 78.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0
  Using cached tensorboard_plugin_wit-1.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (781 kB)
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1
  Using cached google_auth_oauthlib-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting ptyprocess
  Using cached ptyprocess-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting argon2-cffi-bindings
  Downloading argon2_cffi_bindings-21.2.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (86 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 86.2/86.2 kB 24.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting future>=0.15.2
  Downloading future-0.18.3.tar.gz (840 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 840.9/840.9 kB 104.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0
  Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (25 kB)
Collecting jupyterlab-pygments
  Downloading jupyterlab_pygments-0.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting nbclient>=0.5.0
  Downloading nbclient-0.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (71 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 72.0/72.0 kB 26.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tinycss2
  Downloading tinycss2-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (132 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 132.2/132.2 kB 51.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting defusedxml
  Downloading defusedxml-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting bleach
  Downloading bleach-6.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 162.5/162.5 kB 55.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting mistune<3,>=2.0.3
  Downloading mistune-2.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting pandocfilters>=1.4.1
  Downloading pandocfilters-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.7 kB)
Collecting qtpy>=2.0.1
  Downloading QtPy-2.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (84 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 84.9/84.9 kB 35.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting antlr4-python3-runtime==4.9.2
  Downloading antlr4-python3-runtime-4.9.2.tar.gz (117 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 117.2/117.2 kB 40.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pydantic<2.0,>=1.9
  Downloading pydantic-1.10.7-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.2/3.2 MB 101.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting s3transfer<0.7.0,>=0.6.0
  Downloading s3transfer-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 79.6/79.6 kB 35.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting jmespath<2.0.0,>=0.7.1
  Downloading jmespath-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting botocore<1.30.0,>=1.29.102
  Downloading botocore-1.29.102-py3-none-any.whl (10.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.6/10.6 MB 94.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting rsa<5,>=3.1.4
  Downloading rsa-4.9-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1
  Downloading pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 155.3/155.3 kB 53.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0
  Downloading cachetools-5.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0
  Using cached requests_oauthlib-1.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting zipp>=0.5
  Downloading zipp-3.15.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.8 kB)
Collecting parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.0
  Downloading parso-0.8.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (100 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 100.8/100.8 kB 39.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pyrsistent!=0.17.0,!=0.17.1,!=0.17.2,>=0.14.0
  Downloading pyrsistent-0.19.3-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 57.5/57.5 kB 21.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting importlib-resources>=1.4.0
  Downloading importlib_resources-5.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Collecting pkgutil-resolve-name>=1.3.10
  Downloading pkgutil_resolve_name-1.3.10-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
Collecting mdit-py-plugins~=0.2.1
  Downloading mdit_py_plugins-0.2.7-py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 41.0/41.0 kB 13.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading mdit_py_plugins-0.2.6-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting mypy-extensions>=0.2.0
  Downloading mypy_extensions-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
Collecting wcwidth
  Downloading wcwidth-0.2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2
  Downloading charset_normalizer-3.1.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (195 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 195.9/195.9 kB 67.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /home/m992c693/anaconda3/envs/qhack_paper/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests~=2.18->cirq-aqt==1.1.0->cirq>=0.9->pennylane-cirq==0.14.0->-r src/requirements.txt (line 22)) (2022.12.7)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Downloading idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 61.5/61.5 kB 24.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Downloading urllib3-1.26.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 140.9/140.9 kB 55.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting cffi>=1.0.1
  Downloading cffi-1.15.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (442 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 442.7/442.7 kB 93.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting soupsieve>1.2
  Downloading soupsieve-2.4-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting webencodings
  Downloading webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting pure-eval
  Downloading pure_eval-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting asttokens>=2.1.0
  Downloading asttokens-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting executing>=1.2.0
  Downloading executing-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting pycparser
  Using cached pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
Collecting googleapis-common-protos<2.0dev,>=1.56.2
  Downloading googleapis_common_protos-1.59.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (223 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 223.6/223.6 kB 77.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0
  Downloading google_api_core-1.33.2-py3-none-any.whl (115 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 115.5/115.5 kB 47.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading google_api_core-1.33.1-py3-none-any.whl (115 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 115.5/115.5 kB 35.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading google_api_core-1.33.0-py3-none-any.whl (115 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 115.2/115.2 kB 40.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading google_api_core-1.32.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 93.6/93.6 kB 34.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting google-auth<3,>=1.6.3
  Downloading google_auth-1.35.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (152 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 152.9/152.9 kB 55.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0
  Downloading cachetools-4.2.4-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6
  Downloading pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 77.1/77.1 kB 32.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pydantic<2.0,>=1.9
  Downloading pydantic-1.10.6-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.2/3.2 MB 99.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pydantic-1.10.5-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.2/3.2 MB 99.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pydantic-1.10.4-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.2/3.2 MB 101.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pydantic-1.10.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (13.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 13.6/13.6 MB 74.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pydantic-1.10.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (13.5 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 13.5/13.5 MB 93.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pydantic-1.10.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (13.5 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 13.5/13.5 MB 92.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pydantic-1.9.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (12.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 12.8/12.8 MB 91.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pyquil>=3.2.0
  Downloading pyquil-3.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 221.5/221.5 kB 73.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pyquil-3.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 221.4/221.4 kB 49.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pyquil-3.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 221.4/221.4 kB 78.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting qcs-api-client<0.22.0,>=0.20.13
  Downloading qcs_api_client-0.21.3-py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 147.4/147.4 kB 36.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pyquil>=3.2.0
  Downloading pyquil-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 221.3/221.3 kB 48.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pyquil-3.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 221.0/221.0 kB 77.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pyquil-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 221.0/221.0 kB 48.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pydantic to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pyasn1-modules to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1
  Downloading pyasn1_modules-0.2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (131 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 131.4/131.4 kB 45.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of proto-plus to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting proto-plus>=1.20.0
  Downloading proto_plus-1.22.1-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 47.9/47.9 kB 20.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pkgutil-resolve-name to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of parso to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.0
  Downloading parso-0.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 94.0/94.0 kB 26.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of mypy-extensions to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting mypy-extensions>=0.2.0
  Downloading mypy_extensions-0.4.4.tar.gz (4.2 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of jmespath to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting jmespath<2.0.0,>=0.7.1
  Downloading jmespath-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of importlib-resources to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting importlib-resources>=1.4.0
  Downloading importlib_resources-5.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of idna to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Downloading idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 61.2/61.2 kB 23.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of cachetools to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0
  Downloading cachetools-4.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of google-auth to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting google-auth<3,>=1.6.3
  Downloading google_auth-1.34.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (152 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 152.9/152.9 kB 38.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of google-api-core[grpc] to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of executing to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of duet to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of charset-normalizer to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2
  Downloading charset_normalizer-3.0.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (195 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 195.4/195.4 kB 59.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of cffi to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting cffi>=1.0.1
  Downloading cffi-1.15.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (446 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 446.7/446.7 kB 87.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of certifi to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Downloading certifi-2022.12.7-py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 155.3/155.3 kB 50.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0
  Downloading cachetools-5.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of botocore to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of asttokens to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting asttokens>=2.1.0
  Downloading asttokens-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of tinycss2 to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting tinycss2
  Downloading tinycss2-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of stack-data to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting stack-data
  Downloading stack_data-0.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of qdldl to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting qdldl
  Downloading qdldl-0.1.5.post2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.0/1.0 MB 108.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading qdldl-0.1.5.post0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.0/1.0 MB 90.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading qdldl-0.1.5-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (921 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 921.4/921.4 kB 86.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading qdldl-0.1.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (852 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 852.4/852.4 kB 90.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading qdldl-0.1.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (852 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 852.3/852.3 kB 88.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading qdldl-0.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (847 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 847.4/847.4 kB 76.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading qdldl-0.1.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (828 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 828.7/828.7 kB 81.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of qdldl to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Downloading qdldl-0.0.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (549 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 549.2/549.2 kB 75.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of psutil to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting psutil
  Downloading psutil-5.9.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (295 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 295.6/295.6 kB 88.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. See https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/backtracking for guidance. If you want to abort this run, press Ctrl + C.
```

**Edit**

```
pip install -r src/requirements.txt --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver

ERROR: pip's legacy dependency resolver does not consider dependency conflicts when selecting packages. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
pydantic 1.10.7 requires typing-extensions>=4.2.0, but you'll have typing-extensions 3.7.4.3 which is incompatible.
mdit-py-plugins 0.2.8 requires markdown-it-py~=1.0, but you'll have markdown-it-py 0.6.2 which is incompatible.
markdown-it-py 0.6.2 requires attrs<21,>=19, but you'll have attrs 22.2.0 which is incompatible.
cirq-core 1.1.0 requires networkx~=2.4, but you'll have networkx 3.0 which is incompatible.
grpcio-status 1.53.0 requires grpcio>=1.53.0, but you'll have grpcio 1.32.0 which is incompatible.
google-api-core 1.34.0 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<4.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you'll have protobuf 4.22.1 which is incompatible.
cirq-google 1.1.0 requires protobuf<4,>=3.15.0, but you'll have protobuf 4.22.1 which is incompatible.
qcs-api-client 0.21.3 requires attrs<22.0.0,>=21.3.0, but you'll have attrs 22.2.0 which is incompatible.
pyquil 3.3.4 requires networkx<3.0,>=2.5, but you'll have networkx 3.0 which is incompatible.
pyquil 3.3.4 requires numpy<2.0,>=1.21, but you'll have numpy 1.19.5 which is incompatible.
pyquil 3.3.4 requires scipy<2.0.0,>=1.6.1, but you'll have scipy 1.6.0 which is incompatible.
tensorboard 2.12.0 requires grpcio>=1.48.2, but you'll have grpcio 1.32.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.4.1 requires h5py~=2.10.0, but you'll have h5py 3.8.0 which is incompatible.
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the versions defined might have different package dependency versions referenced by other packages, and they end up downloading each and every dependency for each nested project. This causes each package to be downloaded and then re-downloaded at other versions to check for compatibility.

And then it looks like some packages are defining ranges:

```
Collecting pyquil>=3.2.0
  Downloading pyquil-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 221.3/221.3 kB 48.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pyquil-3.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 221.0/221.0 kB 77.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading pyquil-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
```

which is pulling down 3 different versions, and doing a comparison:

```
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pydantic to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
```

You could try changing your install to use the legacy resolver:

```
pip install -r src/requirements.txt --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
```

Comment: Thank you @pypalams for the response. I edited the question. I am getting the error with legacy resolver.

Comment: As the error indicates, there is most likely a pinned version of a package that will not be compatible, and therefore the versions you have just won't work. One option you have is to run an install with no pinned versions, and then run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` if that's an option, or scour the logs and find which packages are at fault

Comment: should i remove the versions from requirements.txt file and then run the command:  pip install -r src/requirements.txt --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver and after this run pip freeze> requirements.txt  @pypalms ?

Comment: I'm worried the run will end up being just as long or longer. Best bet would be to identify the baseline versions you want, e.g. tensorflow 2.4.1 and instead write them as tensorflow>=2.4.1. This might be worth a read to understand what is happening: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/dependency-resolution/#possible-ways-to-reduce-backtracking